# Can colonists auto change clothes when worn below 50% instead of complaining?

Tags: rimworld

I have learnt that people will complain when anything they wear is below 50% and then complain more and decrease mood as  clothes get worse.

So far I've taken care of it manually and clicked on each person, tell them to drop the worn item, and then I start crafting a new one which they will auto find once it's complete.

I haven't kept a stock of clothes in advance, since crafting takes long, but I was thinking that if I had a stock of new clothes, would they take care of this on their own so that I can forget about it, and would they in this case never get the -3 debuff for worn clothes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a much better way of doing this: managing uniforms. This can be done from the Restrict menu at the bottom (Alpha 16; not sure if applicable for 15).

You start out with a few preset uniform options: Anything (everyone is set to this by default), Soldier, Nudist.
The cool thing is that you can **edit the existing options**.

If you load the "Anything" option, you can change what is allowed and what is not allowed. If you set the quality slider to only allow clothes that are between 51% and 100%, your colonists (that are set to Anything) will never wear worn out clothes that carry a negative mood debuff. When a piece of their gear reaches 50% durability, they will take it off.

**Caveat**: When you do this, your colonists will **never** wear worn out apparel. Even if it is the only option they have. This may be important if you need clothes for warmth (e.g. boreal forest or ice sheet); because in those cases it's better to wear worn out clothes than it is to avoid the mood debuff from wearing worn out clothes.

Comment: Nice update. When posting the original question, I was playing Alpha 12 :P  , version history is here http://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Version_history#Complete_Version_List

Comment: Note that if you force a colonist to wear something (which means telling them to wear it via the right-click menu), they will wear it regardless of uniform settings.  In addition to using this to wear clothes for warmth, you can use this to force your colonists to wear worn out shields or armor during fights.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian: Good point. This can also be done through the uniform manager. Set soldier uniform to allow all qualities, but the day-to-day uniform to be of a certain quality, and you can toggle between the two as you need. Although this approach might not be the best in case of an imminent attack.

Answer (score 6):

I tried this today and can confirm that it works. If there are available clothes of better quality in a stockpile, the person will find them and change his clothes.